# Override a Qt class with an embedded private class

Tags: c++, qt

In many cases, I would like to override a Qt class to extend or modify its behavior. But almost all Qt classes uses an internal private class such as QNetworkDiskCachePrivate inside QNetworkDiskCache. I know there are advantages of this approach. But there is a HUGE problem of the private class: it makes overriding the class a lot more difficult. With other C++ class library with source code, I usually override a class method, copy the code from the implementation in the parent class and make small modifications here and there to achieve the behavior I want. However, in Qt, the private class is not exported and not visible to the derived class. Since Qt classes maintains the critical internal data in the private class through the "d" member, the invisibility of the private internal class makes the possibility of behavior extension very limited. You can only play with the few exposed public method.

I tried extracting the entire source files of the class and renaming the class name and file names. But the Qt class library is so much intertwined that extracting a single class out of it is messy as well in most cases.

Do I miss something here? Or Qt classes are just really bad in terms of extendability?

Comment: Not all Qt classes _should_ be modifiable. I'd say a good 90% of the time, Qt is doing the 'right' thing in terms of extensibility and detail hiding.

Are you sure you're taking the right approach to implementing the functionality you want? Instead of posting about the method you've already picked, you should ask how to accomplish a given task.

Comment: You might want to make this more concrete by explaining specifically what you want to do with `QNetworkDiskCache`. The question would be more answerable, and the answer could give insight to how you might approach similar problems in general.

Answer (score 1):

Qt classes are better than most in terms of extendability; they often have hooks to change their behavior without resorting to copying and pasting an entire method. Having said that, if the generally accepted methods of extending don't work, yes the Qt classes are harder to hack. That's probably a good thing because copying-pasting-and-modifying the base class implementation means that your derived class won't get any improvements or bugfixes that are made in the base class implementation.

If you want to do it, you're going to need to convince your build system to let you include the private headers and then refer to the private classes from your new implementation. Pay attention to the disclaimer in the Qt docs; when you do this you are opening yourself up to breakage with every new version of Qt that is released (Qt only guarantees the public API, and you're messing with its internals). Qt's public API is wonderfully readable and documented; the internal code can be pretty cryptic, so you really, really want to be sure that you can't accomplish what you want with the public API. If you're still resolved to use the private class stuff, [this might help](http://zchydem.enume.net/2010/01/19/qt-howto-private-classes-and-d-pointers/).

Comment: Yes. Copy and paste code from the parent class is the last resort. But when there is no other options, at least it suffices as a workaround. In the real world, not every classes are modified like hell with every new release. Even if it does, it usually doesn't take too much trouble to apply the same patching again in the next version. I did a lot of such fixes with MFC which saved my day many times. But with QT, it's really really painful to do that.

Answer (score -2):

Your approach is wrong and bad! To extend a Qt, and more in general C++, code you don't have to copy the source code and modify it where you need. You should (have to) use extending OOP(Object Oriented Programming) paradigm. In C++ you should write something like:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(){x=1;}
    void writeName(){cout << "my name is A";}
    void writeNumber(){cout << "my number is " << x << endl;}
private:
    int x;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(){}
    void writeName(){cout << "my name is B and i'm better then A" << endl;}
};

int main()
{
   B *b= new B();
   b->writeName();
   b->writeNumber();
   return 0;
}

//output:
my name is B and i'm better then A
my number is 1
```

In this way B does all that base class A does and you add your methods(extend base class) to fit your needs. If you take a look at qt example code this is usually the approach used to do something not included into default qt widget behaviour. In example ItemDelegate customizations: you write your own class MyItemDelegate that extend QItemDelegate: [link](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/itemviews-spinboxdelegate.html)

> Or Qt classes are just really bad in terms of extendability?

Qt is "only" a framework build up C++ language. This means that everything you can do in C++ you can do with Qt.

Comment: Ironically, you just did what you said he shouldn't do: copy the implementation of the overridden method. Your B::writeName() implementation shares a substantial percentage of code with A::writeName().

Comment: maybe it was only an example. ;)

I don't think something like that could be really useful.

Comment: I know the supposedly correct way to extend a C++ class. That's assuming the base class is well designed and free of bugs. But in some cases, you really have to hack into the detailed code of the base class in order to fix a bug or modify a tiny behavior. Using a internal private class makes the task extremely difficult.

Comment: Your approach does not work in case of private implementations which used in Qt.

Comment: This is the only working approch: you doesn't have to use their private data. If you relied on it you would have some big troubles on Qt version changes. While with the approch I suggested even if Qt trolls change anything your code will still work, this is because they provide ABI compatibility: http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/is_qt_binary_compatible Anyway it's just OOP programming. I never heard someone who copied base class code into derivate classes.